# fetching available time slot using join

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a doctor, time slot and an appointment table. such that doctor `has_many` time slots and doctor `has_many` appointments. time slot `has_one` appointment.

timeslot table contains doctor_id and available_slot(this contain a time for appointment).
appointment table has `doctor_id`, `timeslot_id` and `appointment_date`.

**I want to get the time slot of a specific doctor which are not available in appointment table(means which are not taken by any patient).**

Answer (score 0):

```
select columns from timeslot left join appointment on 
timeslot.doctor_id=appointment.doctor_id
timeslot.time_slot_id=appointment.time_slot_id where appointment.doctor_id is null
```

Comment: select * from timeslots left join appointments on 
timeslots.doctor_id=appointments.doctor_id
timeslots.timeslot_id=appointments.timeslot_id where appointments.doctor_id = null
I am using this syntax generating a syntax error.

Comment: what would be the syntax for rails 4 controller?